# variable values not showing during debug vs 2019 16.2.4

Tags: visual-studio-debugging

I have a break point set after I have assigned a value to a local variable. The name of the variable remains grayed out, and I can't see its value when I hover over it. This was working find but has suddenly stopped.

As shown in the code below, I have set two break points, one where I add together two local variables, and one when I instantiate a form. The debugger does not halt at the first break point, but does at the second. When I hover over any of the local variables, I get not recognition of the variable nor its value.

```
int testVariable = 1;
int test2 = 3;
int test3 = 0;
test3 = testVariable+test2; //this is where the breakpoint is - note test3 is grayed out
MainForm main = new MainForm(); // this where the second breakpoint is which does work
main.Show();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> This was working find but has suddenly stopped.

Did you make any changes to your project recently? Nothing is special with your code, I assume this is an issue with your settings or extensions. You can try steps below to resolve this issue:

1. You can try restarting VS and rebuilding the project.
2. If it persists, please reset all your debug-related options (*Tools -> Import and Export settings -> Reset all settings ->No, just reset...*).
3. If it not works, go *Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General* to check both *"Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators"* and *"Use Managed Compatibility Mode"*.

Also, according to [this document](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/debugging-optimized-code/), please avoid debugging optimized code, you can enable the *"Suppress JIT optimizations on module load (Managed only)"* option to check if it helps.

Comment: number 3 worked for me, thanks

Comment: #1 worked for me

Answer (score 26):

The problem I had that I was executing the application in release mode, changing it to Debug resolved the issue.

Comment: @Ramzi Hammouda, you´re right. This is very silly mistake that can happen with the best of us. Thx

Answer (score 10):

This happened to my after updating VS2019 to 16.11.21 . Tried reset all settings, suspend resharper, checked Use Managed Compatibility mode. None worked.

The one that works for me is to **delete the hidden .vs folder in my project folder**.

Once I deleted it, reopen the project, and DataTip returns back to normal.

Comment: Ah, Finally! This worked for me

Comment: Super grateful of this answer. I was troubleshooting it from 2 days and had tried everything. Finally, this helped.

Comment: Worked for me in VS 2022 as well.

Comment: Worked for me as well with one additional caveat - I had to Build-->Clean the solution after deleting the .vs folder and re-opening the solution.